# How to insert backslash into my string in java?

Tags: java, string

I have string, and I want to replace one of its character with backslash \

I tried the following, but no luck.

```
engData.replace("'t", "\\'t")
```

and

```
engData = engData.replace("'t", String.copyValueOf(new char[]{'\\', 't'}));
```

INPUT : "can't"

EXPECTED OUTPUT : "can\'t"

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: A sample I/O with actual and expected output, would help in better understanding of the problem.

Comment: please post inputs & what its result?

Comment: Did you try engData.replace("*character you want to replace*", "\\")

Comment: @R.J please check the latest edit.

Comment: @K.C. Yes I tried it, but no luck.

Comment: @Naresh Noby : you are replacing ('t) with  (\'t)  (and there is no replacing , you have inserted a new character).. in the question you mentioned that you want to replace one of its character with backslash \. so exactly what do you want to do ?

Comment: Thanks to all for the aswers, I got the solution! :)

Comment: Strange. Code which you posted `.replace("'t", "\\'t")` should work fine (demo: https://ideone.com/K0bAo5). Also that code is actually **best\preferred solution** for what you described in the question. If it didn't work fot you it means you had somewhere another problem which was the *real issue* (maybe you simply didn't save your code and was trying to compile its older version which had other problems? - it happens quite often at start of programming).

Comment: Anyway solutions from current answers only add unnecessary burden like: (a) `replaceAll` enables regex syntax, which is not what we want; and (b) solution from currently accepted answer `.replace("'", "\\\'");` adds escaping for `'` which is allowed but **not needed**. IMO none of posted answers (at current time) should be accepted as *preferred* solution for this problem because preferred solution is already in the question itself (I would probably add somewhere at start of the question info like "**false alarm: `.replace("'t", "\\'t");` worked fine, real problem was somewhere else**").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this

```
engData.replace("'", "\\\'");
```

INPUT : can't

EXPECTED OUTPUT : can\'t

Comment: Since it is in a String, there is no need for the `'` to be escaped. Also, this replaces ALL single quotes. This would make `"can't. 'hi'. 'h'"` turn into `"can\'t. \'hi\'. \'h\'"`. The OP seems to have been asking for only the single quotes before a `t` to be changed.

Comment: @ Quincunx : yeah. The question statement is not mentioning the exact expectation. not clear enough. But as we can see this is the accepted answer :)

Comment: @AmitGupta You still have an escaped `'` in the second parameter

Comment: It seems like just `engData.replace("'", "\\'");` is enough, or there's something wrong with that?

Answer (score 9):

Try this..

```
    String s = "can't";
    s = s.replaceAll("'","\\\\'");
    System.out.println(s);
```

out put :

```
    can\'t
```

This will replace every ' occurences with \' in your string.

Answer (score 2):

`String` is immutable in Java. You need to assign back the modified string to itself.

```
engData = engData.replace("'t", "\\'t"); // assign the modified string back.
```

Comment: This seems correct to me. The question was wrong. "I want to replace one of its character with backslash \", but you have to insert a backslash and no character gets replaced ...

Comment: There was no replace with the backslash or anything. Just that the changed string wasn't assigned back, so the changes weren't getting reflected.

Comment: I am sorry for english!

Comment: No problem. You asked a proper question. The solution is to assign back the value. There was nothing wrong with the replace string or the replacement string.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with [regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/):

```
engData = engData.replaceAll("('t)","\\\\$1");
```

The `(` and `)` specify a [group](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html). The `'t` will match any string containing `'t`. Finally, the second part replaced such a string with a backslash character: `\\\\` (four because [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html#regex_backslashes)), and the first group: `$1`. Thus you are replacing any substring `'t` with `\'t`

---

The same thing is possible without regex, what you tried (see [this](http://ideone.com/qaOazN) for output):

```
engData = engData.replace("'t","\\'t"); //note the assignment; Strings are immutable
```

See [`String.replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence%2c%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
class Foobar {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.err.println("asd\\'t".replaceAll("\\'t", "\\\'t"));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For String instances you can use, `str.replaceAll()` will return a new String with the changes requested:

```
String str = "./";
String s_modified = s.replaceAll("\\./", "");
```

Comment: You can also use `str = str.replaceAll("\\./","");` this works fine