# A way to consider the backslash as a normal character

Tags: java, backslash

Is there someone who knows how to consider the backslash as a normal character (not an escape character) in a string in Java?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert backslash into my string in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138363/how-to-insert-backslash-into-my-string-in-java)

Comment: There must be a million questions on Java backslash in SO.

Comment: @rghome yes there is but no one answers my question :(

Comment: Bad luck. Two notes: _(File system)_ For Window file paths a normal slash `/` in general works too.  _(SQL)_ For composing SQL text with separate strings, a Prepared statement with a placeholder and  setting parameters escapes backslash and quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Java doesn't have anything like the verbatim string literals of C# and other languages.

Backslash is *always* an escape character in a Java string or character literal. Note that it's only in literals that Java cares, as a *language*. The language itself has no special behaviour when it comes to backslashes which already exist within string objects. Some libraries (e.g. regular expressions) treat backslash specially too, but that's a very different matter... and it's important to differentiate between "I already have a backslash in my string, and I'm trying to use the string in a particular context which is sensitive to backslashes" and "I'm trying to *create* a string with a backslash in, within Java source code, using a string literal".

If you have a text which can include backslashes and you want to simplify it for readability, two options present themselves:

- Use a different character (e.g. forward slash) and then use `String.replace` to replace all occurrences of the other character with backslash
- Put your text in a text file which you load at execution time

Comment: @VinayPrajapati: Why? It answers the question. (And with the edit, suggests alternatives.)

Comment: the problem is that I have some string variables that probably contain the backslash character. When I want to use them, that causes an execution error (all the string format becomes incomprehensible)

Comment: @Basma: That's not a problem with backslash being an escape character in a string literal then. I suggest you leave this question as it is, but ask a new question explaining what you've actually got and how you're trying to use it.

Comment: Nitpick: string *and character* literals. And backslash-u *Unicode* escapes actually can be written everywhere, but outside of literals are *useful* only in identifiers, and most people who want Unicode identifiers don't need the escapes because they use UTF-something files.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: Well, the question is about strings explicitly... will add about character literals though.

Answer (score 1):

Type backslash again to convert the escape character back into a normal backslash:

`System.out.print("\\");` will print `\`.
`System.out.print("\");` will give an error.